# How do I reset the tutorials in Little Big Planet?

Tags: little-big-planet

I started the tutorials about 6 months ago and recently came back to the game.

I have no idea what was in the tutorials I did 6 months ago, and now I need to replay them

Comment: Offtrack: you just asked question 1337 :) I have a screencap if anyone wants it, or is that lame these days?

Comment: Ha! What an honour, can you upload to imgshack of an equivalent?

Comment: don't have Imageshack account :( anywhere better?

Comment: Well it's an answer now, burn me for it :P but seriously mods, forgive me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the gameplay tutorials, you can get a basic idea of that through the earliest levels, The Gardens, which will go over all the stuff like jumping/gripping/etc. If you mean the creation tutorials, if you hit Square to go to the Poppit menu, then move to the Tools Bag, then hit Square instead of X in the Tools Bag, you'll see the text from the tutorials you've finished already. If it's blank, then you still need to do the tutorial, which you then should be able to do by hitting the ? mark.

Comment: I did it! Can you edit your answer to include "Press square for the popit menu, move to 'Tools Bag' "?

Comment: Also, you can go to the main menu and select Videos and Voice overs. Of course, you don't get to try it out there but is a handy reminder.

Comment: Made the requested edits. That work?